# Proving Rn minus the unit disk is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers, connectedness, path-connected

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{R}^n - \{x | norm(x) \leq 1 \}$ is connected. I was thinking of trying to show that it's path connected but I got stuck.

Comment: You got stuck where? It is pretty simple to show that any couple of distinct points can be joined by a path like /)

Comment: I was trying to explicitly define paths to connect the different parts of the graph but I'm having trouble finding paths that connect the points within the unit square but outside the unit circle.

Comment: You do not need to consider the unit square, assuming we are dealing with the Euclidean norm. Assuming that between $P$ and $Q$ the point $P$ has the least norm, go straight from $P$ to $P\cdot\frac{\|Q\|}{\|P\|}$ then take a walk on a sphere $\|x\|=\|Q\|$ to connect $P\cdot\frac{\|Q\|}{\|P\|}$ with $Q$.

Comment: This fails if $n=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider any two arbitrary points in $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^n - \{x\ |\ norm(x) \leq 1 \}$.  Then $|A| \equiv \mbox{norm }(A) >1$ and $|B| \equiv \mbox{norm }(B) > 1$.

Choose any positive $\epsilon < \min(|A|-1,|B|-1)$ and let $A^\star = \frac{1+\epsilon}{\lvert A \rvert}A$ and $B^\star = \frac{1+\epsilon}{\lvert B \rvert}B$.

Now consider the path $P$ consisting of:  the straing line $AA^\star$; followed by the great circle along the $n$-sphere of radius $1+\epsilon$ centered at the origin, passing through $A^\star$ and $B^\star$; followed by a straight line from $B^\star$ to $B$.  $P$ is continuous, goes from $A$ to $B$, and is always in $\mathbb{R}^n - \{x\ |\ norm(x) \leq 1 \}$.

Since $A$ and $B$ were arbitray points in $\mathbb{R}^n - \{x\ |\ norm(x) \leq 1 \}$, this shows $\mathbb{R}^n - \{x\ |\ norm(x) \leq 1 \}$ is path connected.

Comment: Made an edit to your answer, please check if I made it right :)

Comment: What is the point of choosing this epsilon?

Comment: @Gabriel The whole point to it is to get some path around the unit ball which doesn't touch that ball.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the unit ball and choose distinct $x,y \notin B$.

It is clear that there is some $R$ such that the sphere of radius $R$ does not intersect $B$.

The path $t \mapsto t x$, $t \in [1,{R \over \|x\|}]$ connects $x$ to the $R$ sphere and lies in $B^c$. Similarly for $y$. It is clear that the $R$ sphere is path connected. Hence there is a path from $x \to y$. Hence $B^c$ is path connected.